# Unidentified sorting algorithm

Tags: javascript, sorting

Does anyone recognize this sorting algorithm? I have provided the code for it in javascript and you can see it working on this link http://jsfiddle.net/EBC6T/6/

```
var unsortedArr=[4,3,2,1];

var swap=function(arr,i,j){
   var temp=arr[i];
   arr[i]=arr[j];
   arr[j]=temp;
};

var theUnknownSort=function(arr){
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length;j++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
        swap(arr,i,j);
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += "<li>"+arr+"</li>";
        }
    }
 }

};

theUnknownSort(unsortedArr);
```

Sequence of sort:

```
3,4,2,1
2,4,3,1
1,4,3,2
1,3,4,2
1,2,4,3
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: this sorting looks like the most inefficient of all the others.

Comment: Is it bubble sort? It looks pretty much like that.

Comment: I think some combinations are missing. I.e. '2,3,1,4', etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a naive form of [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) since it immediately swaps the indices instead of just remembering the index and swapping it once after the inner loop is done.

the improved form is:

```
for(all i in array){
  for (all j==i+1 in array){
    compare i to all j, remember lowest number minj
  }
  swap(i,minj) if minj<i
}
```

still it has horrible performance with `O(n²)`.

Comment: +1 for `not bubble sort`!

Comment: You're right, not bubble sort. Just appeared as such at the first glance +1.

Comment: if it was the bubble sort the following sequence would be:
[4,3,2,1]
[3,4,2,1]
[3,2,4,1]
[3,2,1,4]
[2,3,1,4]
[2,1,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]

Comment: @JSEL You can't see the deleted answers, that's why you missed the point, where 3 other answers said this was bubble sort - that's why Kevins comment.